# Django send mail with ics attachment encoding error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send an ics attachment to the clients with django:

```
message = EmailMessage(subject, html_string, from_email, [to_email])
if attach:
    message.attach_file(attach, 'text/calendar; charset=UTF-8')
message.send()
```

Before sending the file it has the correct characters (on the server) like: Hajvágás

And after I send it, it looks like this: HajvÃ¡gÃ¡s

I checked multiple email clients like gmail and spark and all of them show the same gibberish.

Also the ics file is validated.

Is there a way to send it correctly?